# Visual studio 2015 deletes file on save - cordova Solution

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I've just updated windows to the creative suite, and now when i run visual studio to develop my app (using an apache cordova solution), when ever i hit save on a file, it removes the file from the solution and closes the editing window for the file.

I can do a CTRL+F for content within the file, then it will open the file again and bring it back to the solution, but now the file in the solution has no 'lock' icon.

I have tried updating visual studio, but apparently i have the latest version of update 3 already.

It wasn't doing this before this morning which is when i got the creators update for windows, so i can only assume it was something to do with this?

If any one can help, it would be much appreciated, its driving me insane! I get no errors what so ever.

Comment: Do you have any addons installed? Like ReSharper or something?

Comment: Unfortunately not no, and I know this is a stab in the dark with the info I've given, but I'm hoping some one else had this issue and solved it :/

Comment: I found a blog post about this issue with VS2008 and about 5 people had the same issue, was not resolved. A Microsoft employee asked some questions though.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here (since a week). When I edit and save a random file from my Cordova project, it closes from view and removes from the project. Only way to get it back is "add existing". VS2015 Community with Cordova + Win10. I have a feeling it's caused by the latest Windows Update, as I've been always been working with Update 3 of Visual Studio and nothing has changed in this project in the last months. Checked with a colleague and he has exactly the same problem after installing "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1709", so this is definitely the cause of the problem. I'll try

Comment: @MarijnDewulf Did you try a rollback for this update? Any solution?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on Ctrl + S, and file closed after save. Then i had to include it in project again to re-open. I still unable to found solution. :-(

Comment: We have the same problem. We unload and reload the project to get the file back in the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft have issued a patch to fix this behaviour.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/4089821/files-disappear-from-project-after-saving-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: I cant test if this works, as im now using 2017 which fixed the issue... but i'm going to mark this as the answer! Thanks a lot for the heads up for every one :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing this as well, and I just noticed that it only happens in Cordova projects.

My current work around is File -> Recent Files and select the file(s) that just closed. The file(s) re-open and reappear in the file tree.

I think they must be re-opened for VS to find all the files necessary for a build.

Answer (score 0):

This issue just occurred on my system too. Only files in the www folder have this issue. You can close a file that has not been edited. Or restart VS to fix.

Issue:
Saving a file closes it from view and removes it from the project. It is however saved and you can use add-existing to get it back. Everything else seems to be normal. 
Using vs2015 community with cordova on win 10.

Comment: My exact issue... 

my way of fixing it, was to use visual studio to run it with cordova etc etc, then open the project using another text editor (brackets in my case) which then allowed me to edit it. 'On Save' of each file also reloads the browser window, so quite handy.

Comment: I've found that unloading the project and then reloading it shows the file again

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by rolling back to old build.

Undoing Feature update to Windows 10, version 1709 solved the problem.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 2017 and this doesn't have the issue. I'm guessing the development team for 2015 aren't fussed about it any more and expect people to upgrade to 2017 :/