# VS 2015 on save file show exclamation symbol and gets hidden

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Dears,

I am facing a very strange issue in VS 2015, whenever i save any file , in solution explorer it shows exclamation symbol and suddenly file gets hidden. File is not visible then, i have to load solution again to view the file.

Similar issue was happening on VS 2017, but there files were not getting hidden, but now when i updated VS 2017 everything is running fine there.

My VS 2015 is already updated (update 3). BTW Its only happening for Apache Cordova Projects, even if i make new project. MVC etc type of projects are working fine on VS 2015. Attached screenshot.

[image]

Please advise if someone faced similar issue.

Thank You

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201678/visual-studio-2015-deletes-file-on-save-cordova-solution but no solution so far

Comment: Yes this is strange issue and it only started after this new Window 10 update, before i was using vs 2015 from a long time with this same project and all was good but now i switched to VS 2017, everything works fine there.